# How to populate TableViewer in a vertical fashion

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

I have a `TreeViewer` which contains some nodes which each node has some attributes with their corresponding values. I have also a `TableViewer` to show the attributes and their corresponding values of the selected node from the `TreeViewer`. In the table there are only 2 columns, one showing the attribute name (on the left) and the other one showing the value of that attribute (on the right).

I have the attributes and values in a `HashMap`(attributes, value)

But since each node is representing one object, the call to `AttributeLabelProvider` (implements `ITableLabelProvider`) method `getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex)` only happens once. But I need to create 10 rows to show all the 10 attributes on the attribute column and their values on the right column.

```
tableViewer.setInput(selectedNode);
// The following is where I have implemented IStructuredContentProvider to use as my content provider
@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    TreeNode TN = (TreeNode) inputElement;
    return TN.getAttributes().values().toArray(); // ***
}
```

*** here I can only pass either `keySet()` or `values()` because my attributes are in a `HashMap`.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one solution, but I am not sure if this is safe. This will return both the values and the keys in an array of Objects[]:

```
@Override
public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
    TreeNode TN = (TreeNode) inputElement;
    return TN.getAttributes().entrySet().toArray();
}
```

Then I used the following in ITableLabelProvider.getColumnText() for columns one and two:

```
col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {   // Column 1 (contains the keys)
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            String str = element.toString();
            String[] parts = str.split("=");
            return parts[0];
        }
    });

col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {  // Column 2 (Contains the values)
        @Override
        public String getText(Object element) {
            String str = element.toString();
            String[] parts = str.split("=");
            return parts[1];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `IStructuredContentProvider.getElements` method must return an array of objects where each object represents a row in the table. So in your case you need to return an array of 10 row objects. If you don't currently have such an object you will have to create one.

The `ITableLabelProvider.getColumnText` method will be passed one of these row objects. You will need to be able to get the column data from your row object.

Comment: Thanks greg-449. I am aware of what you said, but the thing is that my node in the tree is the object that has the attributes which are basically the row objects that you are talking about, but stored in a map. Since it is a map I can either pass values() or Keyset() as the array of objects to     ITableLabelProvider.getColumnText, but I need both the values and keys to put the keys as the left column of my table and the values as the right column.